# Deploy MVC3 on IIS Server - Error 401

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, iis-7.5

So I deployed my website this morning to my test server using "Build Deployment Package" in Visual Studio.

In IIS we import the website and deployed it as a new site, everything is fine there.

But when we launch the browser, we hit an error:

```
HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Most likely causes: 
The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request.
```

We tried to give all access to users for folders and also alternate from anonymous login to form Authentication without success.

Help would be appreciated! Maybe I missed a permission somewhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem:
For some reason, visual studio was not compiling my resources and Dlls in the package.
I had to set all resources in project at Embedded in properties and I manually copy my dlls on the server